# Is there a better way to work with result from JSON and check whether it's blank or not

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use the PostCodeAPI (http://postcodeapi.com.au/) to get Australian postal information based on postcode.

Below would work successfully if a correct postcode is entered in the url (such as 2601.json).

I have used try-except to catch HTTPError, and this is working successfully too.

However, I am just wondering if there's a better way to determine whether **data** has value or not, than using a if-statement in my example.

```
import urllib2
import json

data = []

url = 'http://v0.postcodeapi.com.au/suburbs/26xx.json'
header = {'User-Agent' : 'ubuntu Browser'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=header)

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

try:
    data = json.loads(opener.open(req).read())
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "Request doesn't generate anything."

print data

if data == []:
    print "no data"
else:
    print data[0]['name']
```

Following @mgilson's suggestions, here is the updated version, with changes around (1) date = None and (2) if data

```
import urllib2
import json

data = None

url = 'http://v0.postcodeapi.com.au/suburbs/26xx.json'
header = {'User-Agent' : 'ubuntu Browser'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=header)

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

try:
    data = json.loads(opener.open(req).read())
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "Request doesn't generate anything."

print data

if data:
    print data[0]['name']
else:
    print "no data"
```

Comment: usually `if data` is preferred to `if data == []`, otherwise there isn't a way that is much better (Also, using `None` as a sentinel is probably more idiomatic than `[]` unless you have a reason to use `[]` otherwise).

Comment: @mgilson If using `if data is None` then a return of an empty array would make that statement equate to false, triggering the else clause which would then cause an index out of bounds error. I just tried it.

Comment: @MichaelFourre If I understand you correctly, you only have that problem if you're using `if data == []` instead of `if data`...

Comment: thanks @mgilson for the suggestions. i have updated my code in the post.

Comment: `if data` is valid. The comparison to avoid is `if data is None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you absolutely need to use `urllib2`, I'd suggest using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/%20requests) library. It's a more user-friendly HTTP client and does not raise an HTTPError when encountering an HTTP 404. If a 404 is encountered, you shouldn't even bother trying to parse the body as JSON.

```
import json, requests

url = 'http://v0.postcodeapi.com.au/suburbs/22xx.json'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = [] # set a default value, if you want
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print data[0]['name']
else:
    print "no data"
```

Comment: This would break with any other response code than 200, even if they are valid (e.g. 304). Using this might diagnose a problem that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: If the API returns a valid response for other codes, it'd be trivial to modify this to support it.

Comment: That is true @beetea . I think the conclusion is that there are better ways to handle an instance where no data is received. For example, j4ck posted a response using the JSONDecoderError in an except block using the requests module. Regardless of the returned HTTP status code, the JSON object is what is actually being interpreted.

Comment: I'll let the OP decide, but, in my opinion, blindly parsing a non-200 HTTP response body as JSON and not checking the code at all isn't better in any way.

Comment: Thanks @beetea, I was debating between yours and j4ck's code, and end up using your code as I found yours more versatile in determining the HTTP response codes.

Answer (score 0):

For me if is also required .Still urllib2 is old requests is much simpler for rest api's and web requests.

> class NoDataException(Exception):
>
> > print("No Data Received ")
>
> import requests
>
> url='http://v0.postcodeapi.com.au/suburbs/26xx.json'
>   header = {'User-Agent' : 'ubuntu Browser'}
>
> try:
>
> > r=requests.get(url,header)
> >     if(r.json() is null):
> >      raise NoDataException
> >      #   raise ReadTimeout(inbuilt exception for class not sure if works correctly)
> >         print(r.json())
> >         except NoDataException:
> >         pass;
>
> except Exception as e:
>
> > print("Error Occurred ")

Comment: It's considered bad practice to write too broad `try/except` statements like this. Catching `exceptions` like this is bad too. You should rather limit your `try` statement to one or two lines of code and catch very specific exceptions instead. In this case, the `NoDataException`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of, is this:

```
import requests
import json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
try:
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
except json.decode.DecodeError:
    print("No data")
.. # rest of your code
```

This is similar to your code's `try/except` statement, except that I feel it's a bit more explicit.

Also, `try/except` should be preferred if the majority of calls of the `try` statement succeeds.

Comment: Thanks @j4ck, I love the elegance of your code, thanks for giving me an idea on how to improve my coding style.